# Spring Deserialize manytomany table with extra column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I have a manytomany relation mapped with a custom table to add an extra column. I can deserialize it, but deserialized it shows the elements of the join table, I would to just the joined element. So what I currently get is the following:

```
{
    "id": 122,
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": {
                "materialId": 162,
                "homeworkId": 122
            },
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "materialId": 163,
                "homeworkId": 122
            },
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I would rather get something like this:

```
{
    "id": 122,
    "materials": [
        162, 163
    ]
}
```

I am using standard Spring mapper to deserialize:

```
@GetMapping("/api/homework/get")
public Homework getHomework(@RequestParam Long id) {
    return homeworkService.findById(id).orElseThrow(HomeworkNotFoundException::new);
}
```

I have the following java classes (omitted unnecessary methods and functions)

**Material**

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "typeName")
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope = Material.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FileMaterial.class, name = "fileMaterial"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LinkMaterial.class, name = "linkMaterial")
})

@Entity
@Table(name="material")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Material implements FileOwner {
    private static final String sequenceName = "material_id_sequence";

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=10,  sequenceName=sequenceName, name=sequenceName)
    @GeneratedValue(generator=sequenceName, strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "material", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<HomeworkMaterial> homeworks = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Homework**

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope = Homework.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "homework")
public class Homework {
    private static final String sequenceName = "homework_id_sequence";

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=10,  sequenceName=sequenceName, name=sequenceName)
    @GeneratedValue(generator=sequenceName, strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homework", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<HomeworkMaterial> materials = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**HomeworkMaterial**

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "homework_material")
public class HomeworkMaterial {
    @EmbeddedId
    private HomeworkMaterialId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("materialId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Material material;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("homeworkId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Homework homework;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int position;

    public HomeworkMaterial(Material material, Homework homework, int position) {
        this.material = material;
        this.homework = homework;
        this.position = position;
        this.id = new HomeworkMaterialId(material.getId(), homework.getId());
    }
}
```

**HomeworkMaterialId**

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter
public class HomeworkMaterialId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "material_id")
    private long materialId;

    @Column(name = "homework_id")
    private long homeworkId;
}
```

For standard @manytomany mappings I was able to achieve this behaviour with @jsonignoreproperties but i can not transfer it to custom join-tables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would like an array of numbers being returned to the client.

You could create a getter that returns the array of ids and turn the other relationship as not serializable via annotations.

The fact that you only need one of the ids might be an indication of non ideal mapping in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also thought about the solution with a getter, but is there a way to serialize it afterwards? 
I think the mapping is fine, it is a standard join table for manytomany relations. I just need only one of the ids because the other id is the element itself.